# R: dplyr How to group by then filter rows based on the condition of each group's first row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple data frame such as

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 y=c('a','b','a','c','e','d','e','a','f','c'))
```

[image]

I want to group by x, then if the first row of each x-groups has y == 'a', then get only rows that have y == 'a' | y == 'c'

So I expect the outcome would have row 1, 3, 4, 8, 10

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'x', create an `&` condition - 1) check whether the `first` value of 'y' is 'a', 2) condition that checks for values 'a', 'c' in the column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   filter('a' == first(y), y %in% c('a', 'c')) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     1 c    
4     3 a    
5     3 c
```

---

If we have additional rules, create a named `list` where the names will be expected first values of 'y' and the vector of values to be filtered, then extract the `list` element based on the `first` value of the 'y' and use that vector in the logical expression with `%in%`

```
df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    filter(y %in% list(a = c('a', 'c'), e = 'e')[[first(y)]]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     1 a    
3     1 c    
4     2 e    
5     2 e    
6     3 a    
7     3 c
```

Comment: thank you, it works. But what if I want to make it more complex when adding "if" conditions such as if the first row of each group has y == a then get rows with y == a or y ==c, but if the first row of each group has y == e then get rows with y == e? so now I will expect to have 2 more rows added to the outcome (row 5 and 7)

Comment: @game_of_lies try the update

Comment: @game_of_lies you can also use `if/else`, but this will be more easier to pass more than 2 conditions

Comment: your logic works on my real data, thanks a lot akrun

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `dplyr` option

```
> df %>%
+   filter(y %in% c("a", "c") & ave(y == "a", x, FUN = first))
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 c
4 3 a
5 3 c
```